# The link between large p-values and low power?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, p-value, inference, statistical-power

In Wasserman's book "All of Statistics", page 157, there's the following sentence:

«A large p-value is not strong evidence in favor of $H_0$. A large p-value can occur for two reasons:

- $H_0$ is true, or
- $H_0$ is false and the test has low power.»

Why when we have a low power test, do we have a large p-value?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By definition, "low power" means "tends to have large p-values even for large effect sizes."  I would expect that whatever definition you might know could be translated directly into those terms.  If not, then what definition are you actually using?

Comment: @Anold For a continuous parameter, if the null is true the distribution of p-values will be uniform. If the test has low power, the distribution will tend to move from the uniform to what we'd like (a very right-skew distribution with a lot more mass toward low values of $p$) quite slowly (i.e. to remain near uniform, at least for some typical set of values of $n$). So low power doesn't imply that the p value *will* be large (it may be small for the same reason you can get a small p-value when the null is true), only that it's considerably more likely to be large than if the power was high

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. The definition I'm using for power is that of probability of rejecting $H_0$ given $\theta$. The definition of p-value is probability of having a test statistic equal or more extreme than the one obtain for the sample, given $H_0$ is true. For me it's not clear the connection between low power, and large p-values...

Comment: "Probability of rejecting $H_0$" is the very same thing as "chance that the p-value will be sufficiently small" (when, of course, the null hypothesis does not hold). Thus power is great when that chance is low--which is exactly the same thing as saying the power is low when that chance is high.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for your comment. Could you elaborate a bit more your interesting comment on a answer. I would like to 'dissect' each sentence of your comment, but I don't think I have the knowledge for that. ;)

Comment: @whuber could you please write your first sentence of your 2nd comment in a mathematical formula? How do you compute the p-value when the null doesn't hold?

Comment: Exactly the same way you compute it when the null does hold!  After all, the whole purpose of this procedure is to reason about the distribution *when you don't know what the true distribution is*.  If you want mathematical formulas, then you will wind up with the kinds of expressions that have already been posted in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, power of the test $\delta(X)$ is a function $1 - \beta(\theta)$ where

$$\beta(\theta) = P_{\theta}(\delta(X) = 0) \text{ - probability of accepting $H_0$}$$

So if we have low power and $H_0$ is false, i.e. $1 - \beta(\theta)$ is small for $\theta_1$, then probability of accepting $H_0$ even if it is false is equal to $\beta(\theta_1)$ and is high. If our test has a form: $1[T(X) \ge c_{1 - \alpha}]$ for $c_{1 - \alpha}$ being $1 - \alpha$ quantile of $T(X)$, then

$$P_{\theta_1}(T(X) \ge c_{1 - \alpha}) \text{ is close to 0}$$

Now we know that power of every "decent" test is not lower than its significance level (test is unbiased), thus

$$P_{\theta_1}(T(X) \ge c_{1 - \alpha}) \ge P_{\theta_0}(T(X) \ge c_{1 - \alpha}) \text{ is close to 0}$$

And equivalently, p-value of the test $P \ge \alpha$ almost surely. So, does it imply $\textbf{high}$ $P$? We only know it's larger than $\alpha$ but it doesn't have to be close to $1$.

As to better see why large p-value $P$ means nothing, even assuming $H_0$ to be true, it is known that

$$P_{\theta_0}(P \le q) = q$$

$$$$ So under $H_0$ p-value is distributed $\textbf{uniformly}$ on $[0,1]$. So all that really matters is if equality $P < \alpha$ is true or not, and to the exact value of $P$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by « p-value of the test $P_{\theta_1}\geq \alpha$»... do you mean $P_{\theta_1}(T(X)\geq T(x))\geq \alpha$ ? But for the p-value shouldn't we have $P_{\theta_0}(T(X)\geq T(x))\geq \alpha$

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I corrected my answer

Comment: Isn't $P_{\theta_0}(T(X)\geq c_{1-\alpha})=\alpha$?  Is $P=P(T(X)\geq T(x)|\theta_0)$?
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: $P_{\theta_0}(T(X) \ge c_{1 - \alpha}) \le \alpha$, and yes